# Java Servlet: pass data to javascript every second to update a game

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a html like this:

```
<div id="content">

  <div id="game-field">
    <div id="1"></div>...<div id="n"></div>
  </div>

  <button id="start-button">Start</button>
</div>
```

And javascript like this - it sends a request to a servlet that returns a JSON, then javascript looks puts response JSON into an array and changes game field's divs' colors if servlet told so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#start-button", function () {  
        $.get("start", function (response) {    
            var responseField = new Array();

            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                for (var e=0; e<jsonData[i].length; e++)  {
                    responseField.push(jsonData[i][e]);
                }
            }

            var fieldDiv = document.getElementById("game-field");
            for (var i=0; i<fieldDiv.children.length; i++)  {
                    if (responseField[i]==1)  {
                        fieldDiv.children[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
                    }
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to be able to do something similar every second. When a start button is clicked I want a loop get activated inside my servlet, that loop would create a response JSON and send it to javascript every second. For every JSON received javascript would have to update the `game-field` div. What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: you might want to look at the setInverval js built-in method but the trigger will start at your js code not on the servlet

Comment: Servlets works according to request response mechanism means only gives response when you request. However, there is something that may solves your porblem. Take a look at server push. When something changed on server that you interested, server informs the client. Here is a useful information: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html